# MUI Autocomplete API: when I paste space-delimited text,on enter event a single tag is created for it. Can multiple tags be created on "enter" event?

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, jsx

I am using MUI Autocomplete control in my reactjs application. Right now if I paste a custom (not available in list of options) space-delimited content e.g. 3N1CE2CPXEL289419 3N1BC1AP8AL399166 , on hit of enter button a single tag is created for it as : [Autocomplete API image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSbSE.png)

So I have a scenario where user pastes space-delimited text. Is it possible that a single tag is created for each space-delimited value i.e. one for 3N1CE2CPXEL289419 and one for 3N1BC1AP8AL399166 on hit of enter button?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below is how we achieve abv -

```
                   <Autocomplete
                    multiple
                    limitTags={2}
                    id="tags-filled"
                    onChange={onChange}
                    size="small"                   
                    onInputChange={onInputChange}
                    options={rowData.map((option) => option.vinno)}
                    value={autoCompleteValue}
                    freeSolo
                    loading
                    //defaultValue={[top100Films[13].title]}                    
                    //onSelect={(event) => onSelect(event, 'tags')}
                    /* either render tags will work or renderoption */
                    renderTags={(value, getTagProps) =>
                        value.map((option, index) => (
                            <Chip variant="outlined" onDelete={onDelete} label={option} {...getTagProps({ index })} />
                            // <Chip variant="outlined" onDelete={onDelete} label={option} {...getTagProps({ index })} onDelete={onDelete} />
                        ))
                    }
                    renderInput={(params) => (
                        <TextField
                            {...params}                            
                            variant="outlined"
                            label="VinNOs"
                            placeholder="Favorites"
                            onKeyDown={e => {
                                if (e.key === "Enter" && e.target.value) {
                                    let text = e.target.value;
                                    if (text.includes(" ")) {
                                        let vinnos = text.split(" ");
                                        setAutoCompleteValue(autoCompleteValue.concat(vinnos));

                                    } else {
                                        setAutoCompleteValue(autoCompleteValue.concat(e.target.value));
                                    }
                                }
                            }}
                        />
                    )}
```